# What does this statement mean in java jdk 1.8 ( java.util.Map)

Tags: java

There is a statement in the code shown below that I can't understand its meaning.I hope someone can explain it to me. I cannot find the answer with Google.T_T

```java
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>> comparingByValue() {
            return (Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> & Serializable)
                (c1, c2) -> c1.getValue().compareTo(c2.getValue());
}
```

look at this statement
`Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> & Serializable`

I am confused about `&` appearing here.

Comment: It's an intersection type. It just means the returned type is a comparator that's also serializable.